# Need help with Cross Browser Inconsistencies in overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

### RESOLVED

I found the issue and am sorry to say it is quite idiotic. On some pages there was an extra closing bracket after the script type=javascript. Apparently Chrome and Firefox ignore the issue but Safari and IE threw up display errors. Thank you to everybody for the excellent support and guidance on the matter. of note, i decided to go with the .show() method as it seemed most logical.

---

I have the following javascript snippet at the top of my page which validates 2 fields within a login form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('#submit').click(function () {

            $('#login_form span').hide();

            if ($("input#user").val() == "") {
                $("span#user").show();
                $("input#user").focus();  
                return false;  
            }

            if ($("input#pw").val() == "") {
                $("span#pw").show();
                $("input#pw").focus();  
                return false;  
            }

            var overlay = $('<div id="overlay">');
            $('body').append(overlay);
        });
    });
</script>
```

When a form is submitted (submit is clicked) the function is run which checks to make sure the 2 fields: pw and user have some content. If they do, it opens an overlay script to cover the screen. The function above sits at the top of my screen (in the head)

The CSS for the overlay is:

```
#overlay { background:#000 url(../images/loader.gif) center no-repeat; opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity = 50); width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1000; }
```

In Chrome:
The function works well but the 'loading' image within the overlay does not show.

In Firefox:
Nearly the same as Chrome but the loading image DOES work if the javascript call is made at the bottom of the page.

In IE:
if the function stays in the head, my page is completely blank (though no server errors). Once I move to the bottom of the page, the loading image appears randomly and if it does, it is VERY slow in its animation.

perhaps I am doing something wrong but trying to build for all three browsers on something this simple is making me bonkers.

Any suggestions for improvement?

Thanks ahead of time.

### UPDATE

First off thank you all for your suggestions so far. I have tried and number and get various results from each (as well as different results when run locally versus on our apache server).

One page in particular that seems to be of fury is this one:
https://www.nacdbenefits.com/myadmin/password-reset

In IE, the page just opens to a grey screen. I have updated the code to imbed the div id in the page itself and simply 'show' on a submit but apparently something else is catching a long the way.

### UPDATE 2

Something else must be causing this to malfunction. When i strip the code even to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    });
</script>
```

unless I move the code to the bottom of the page, IE just shows a dark screen with nothing there (no server errors again and no JS errors at page bottom).

Comment: for one thing, i think you should rename your ids. IDs no matter if it was a span or an input should be UNIQUE. your input and spans both have #pw ids, which MIGHT be a reason for the browser inconsistency(different browsers sometimes treat same ids differently) if you need the same "name" for your elements, use class instead

Comment: The last line should be `var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');`; however this (probably) has nothing to do with the problem you mentioned.

Comment: @corroded: after looking at the code, I do not think it matters; if you assume that user can hit the submit button only once.

Comment: @Salman A: would you assume that the user will always follow our assumptions? :)

Comment: @corroded: Darn, just re-read the code and your comment. You're right.

Comment: Don't ever give a button in a form a name or id of "submit", it will shadow the form's submit method.

Comment: @RobG - thanks for the comment, do you have any underlying proof on this? I've used 'submit' as the name for a submit button for years without issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have the overlay already existant in the page's HTML but hidden (`display: none;`), so that the background image is preloaded. Then, once my button is clicked, I would `.show()` it.

Comment: fixed a very dumb mistake, thanks for your help and suggestion though. I decided to go with the route you describe above.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code has a bug. I'm suprised Firefox manages to make something out of it. According to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) you should pass it a string or an element. You're attempting to pass it a jQuery selector result (and a broken one at that). Remember, in jQuery `$()` is a function call! Compare your code (condensed):

```
$('body').append($('<div id="overlay">'));
```

with this (no `$()` call):

```
$('body').append('<div id="overlay" />');
```

or this (note closing the div tag):

```
$('body').append($('<div id="overlay" />'));
```

Comment: Isn't he also missing the slash on closing tag?
That is:  '<div id="overlay" /> '
note the "/> at the end of the div tag.

Comment: On the [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) documentation page, there is an example that says that you can do `var newdiv1 = $('<div id="object1"/>')` and 
`$('body').append(newdiv1);`.

Comment: @Salman: Ah, I see. But the cause is still the same. As per selbie's comment, the HTML should be self-contained (i.e. it should have a closing tag). So the OP is still passing the result of a broken jQuery() call to .append(). I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Salman: Yup, after your and selbie's comment I re-read .appends() and noted it also needs self-contained tags as strings.

Comment: @Sander Marechal and Salman A - tried all of the above unsuccessfully. Also corrected the id issues as well as append the code to the body but no luck so far.

Comment: @JM4: Then I suggest that you put your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and reproduce your issue there. If you give us actual running (malfunctioning) code to play with, we can solve it much faster!

Comment: @Sander Marechal - I posted the actual URL affected in my first update. View source seems to show everything that could affect the page.

Comment: just kill me - I found the issue, on some pages there was an extra closing bracket after the script type=javascript. Apparently Chrome and Firefox ignore the issue but Safari and IE threw up display errors.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered having the overlay as part of your page's code, but simply `display: none` by default, and then simply `.show()`ing it when you want it to appear?

Comment: thanks I went with this route, only gave NeXXeus credit because I *think* he was first

Answer (score 1):

The head/bottom-of-page inconsistency can be fixed by running your binding when the DOM is ready, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submit').click(function () {

        // code omitted for brevity

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: He's already doing that - `$(document).ready(function () {});` is same as `$(function () {});`

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: and i think jquery selectors using the $() will only be called after the document is ready

Comment: @corroded no, only the functions that are passed to `$()` will be called after DOM is ready